# Overlapping data lines with Flot Javascript plotting library

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I have to draw multiple lines and would like to plot a tooltip on the data point when mouse hovering. However, some might share the same (x, y). This results in overlapping points. They are plotted on top of each other.

It seems the "plothover" event only returns the data on the very top which is drawn at the last. As a result, the tooltip is only for that point. I want to draw multiple tooltips when multiple data points are hovered.

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, looking at the source, `flot` will only find the top most point on the `plothover`.  The simplest approach is just to do the work yourself.  Here's a generic search for the `plothover` bind:

```
    if (item) {
        var content = item.series.label;
        var someData = plot.getData();
        for (var i = 0; i < someData.length; i++){
            if (someData[i].label == item.series.label){
                continue; // skip item's series...
            }
            for (var j=0; j < someData[i].data.length; j++){
                if (someData[i].data[j][0] == item.datapoint[0] &&
                    someData[i].data[j][1] == item.datapoint[1]){
                      content += ' ' + someData[i].label; 
                }
            }                
        }
        showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY, content);
    }
```

Fiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7AXY8/).

---

Full Code:

```js
$(function () {

    var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"),[ 
        { data: [[0,0],[1,1],[2,2]], label: "Line One"},
        { data: [[0,2],[1,1],[2,0]], label: "Line Two"},
        { data: [[0,0],[0.5,1],[1,1],[2,3]], label: "Line Three"} 
    ], {
        series: {
            lines: { show: true },
            points: { show: true }
        },
        grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true }
    });

    function showTooltip(x, y, contents) {
        $('#tooltip').html(contents);
        $('#tooltip').css({
            top: y + 5,
            left: x + 5,
            display: 'block'});
    }

    $("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
        if (item) {
            var content = item.series.label;
            var someData = plot.getData();
            for (var i = 0; i < someData.length; i++){
                if (someData[i].label == item.series.label){
                    continue;   
                }
                for (var j=0; j < someData[i].data.length; j++){
                    if (someData[i].data[j][0] == item.datapoint[0] &&
                        someData[i].data[j][1] == item.datapoint[1]){
                          content += ' ' + someData[i].label; 
                    }
                }                
            }
            
            
            
            showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY, content);
        }
        else 
        {
            $("#tooltip").css('display','none');       
        }

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.flotcharts.org/javascript/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
<br/><br/>
<div id="placeholder" style="width:400px;height:300px;"></div>
<div id="tooltip" style="position: absolute;
            display: none;            
            border: 1px solid #fdd;
            padding: 2px;
            background-color: #fee;
            opacity: 0.80"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @HarshaMV, the flot GitHub hasn't been updated for over 2 years, so I"m not sure what sort of update you are looking for.  Does my solution above no longer work?

Comment: not able to get it to work. i will look more closely :)

Comment: @HarshaMV, if you want to write up a new question, I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38762745/line-graph-using-flot-is-over-lapping